# Libgdx Freetypefontgenerator error

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to use the freetypefontgenerator directly from my phone using the AIDE app. I have done all the steps shown in this article : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype

However I still get this exception : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.StreamUtils.copyStream
And it says the error comes from the freetypefontgenerator init-method.

Did I miss something or is this an issue with AIDE? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!! I updated all jars and linked my android project manually .to freetype AND freetype natives. Thanks anyway :)